# Parse Javascript upload file return broken link

Tags: javascript, parsing, file-upload

The function below grabs a name and a picture location taken by the user using their phone's camera stored using store.js.

The link below is the link to the picture on the parse server, it's broken.

http://files.parsetfss.com/a190851f-6d14-428e-9b8c-d439dad00634/tfss-ecd5c01d-f142-40ae-bdc3-616ec35f4e38-profile.jpg

```
function serversave(thisstatus)
{         

            var file = store.get("piclocation");
            var name = store.get("username");
            var parseFile = new Parse.File("profile.jpg", {base64:file});
            console.log (parseFile);
            parseFile.save().then(function() 
            {
                var StatusUpdate = Parse.Object.extend("StatusUpdate");
                var statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate();
                statusUpdate.set("name", name);
                statusUpdate.set("status", thisstatus);
                statusUpdate.set("profilepic", parseFile);
                statusUpdate.save(null, {
                success: function(statusUpdate) 
                {
                  $cordovaToast.show('Shared!', 'short', 'bottom').then(function(success) {

                  }, function (error) {});
                },
                error: function(statusUpdate, error) { alert(error.message);
                }   

            }, 
            function(error) {alert(error.message)});

        });
    }
```

I can't seem to get this function to successfully upload an image to the parse server. Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Is the `var file` supposed to be used somewhere?  Maybe when getting the file to upload?

Comment: Yes it is  var parseFile = new Parse.File("profile.jpg", {base64:**file**});

Comment: MIssed that ... thanks!

Comment: Yea no problem. Any ideas why this is failing?

Comment: have you ever take a look at: https://www.parse.com/questions/uploading-files-to-parse-using-javascript-and-the-rest-api

Comment: I figured out the problem, it has to do with the cordova camera options.